# Can "to escape" also mean "to go on holiday"?

Tags: meaning

The Macmillan Dictionary s.v. "[escape (verb)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/escape#escape_35)" says that "to escape" can also mean

> to go away on holiday

in informal contexts, e.g. "We're hoping to escape to the Algarve in May". I can't find this meaning in any other dictionary at my disposal. Is it actually used in this sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *escape* is often used (with *to*) in the context of a holiday trip. You can find many examples [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=escape%20to&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0). Also, the sense you found in Macmillan can also be found in [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=escape&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=):

> (v) **escape**, **get away** (remove oneself from a familiar environment, usually for pleasure or diversion) "*We escaped to our summer house for a few days*"; "*The president of the company never manages to get away during the summer*"

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is. It usually implies "escaping from city life/worries/routines/reality".

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  Check out http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/4-day-queenstown-nature-and-luxury-escape

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find it defined as such in any other dictionary, but I do recall seeing it being used as a noun with that meaning at least thrice.

According to the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escape) (and most other dictionaries), its general meaning would also conform with that, as in escaping your normal life.

Answer (score 1):

An expression that comes to mind is *escaping the [rat race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_race).*

Comment: That will be "rat race" not rate race. The website is not allowing me to edit, as its is less than 6 characters long. :/

Comment: @Playmaker- my bad. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Another example ... [**21 hottest Carribean escapes**](http://www.travelchannel.com/interests/beaches/articles/21-hottest-caribbean-escapes) ... they are not talking about jailbreaks, they are talking about going to Antigua for a week to get away from everyday concerns...

This usage of "escape" is common in the US.  Are those who "couldn't find it" from the UK?